# Animations incredibly slow on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, gsap

I've just created my first web app for the company I'm currently working for, explaining to the none creatives in the company what the "design team" as we are known (despite having developers) do.

http://staging.catalysis.co.uk/designteam/

I've been learning to code for about 4 months and took it upon myself to design and create this all on my own, it's been tough but finally today there is something workable enough to upload to our servers.

However I'm experiencing a few bits of buggy behaviour that I've been unable to diagnose. I have a feeling it's because of my lack of knowledge on best practice structuring in JS, but the animations that are non-css (I used GSAP) for the opening and closing of the "info" pages are appearing incredibly slow on mobile.

This is the logic I'm using to display the info for each iteration of the cards:

```
var info = $('.info');

info.click(function(){
    var gp = $(this).parent().parent(),
        gpInfoBG2 = gp.parent().siblings(".info-bg-close"),
        gpInfoBG = gp.parent().siblings(".info-bg");

    if ($(this).is('.first')) {
        gp.css({"display": "none"});
        backgroundIn(gp.siblings(".infotext-one"), gpInfoBG, gpInfoBG2);
        gp.siblings(".infotext-one").addClass('open');

    } else if ($(this).is('.second')) {
        gp.css({"display": "none"});
        backgroundIn(gp.siblings(".infotext-two"), gpInfoBG, gpInfoBG2);
        gp.siblings(".infotext-two").addClass('open');

    } else if ($(this).is('.third')) {
        gp.css({"display": "none"});
        backgroundIn(gp.siblings(".infotext-three"), gpInfoBG, gpInfoBG2);
        gp.siblings(".infotext-three").addClass('open');

    } else if ($(this).is('.fourth')) {
        gp.css({"display": "none"});
        backgroundIn(gp.siblings(".infotext-four"), gpInfoBG, gpInfoBG2);
        gp.siblings(".infotext-four").addClass('open');
    }
});

function backgroundIn(elemObject, infoBG, infoBG2) {

    var tl = new TimelineMax({onComplete:showText}),
        button = infoBG.siblings('.button-container'),
        line1 = button.children('.line-one'),
        line2 = button.children('.line-two');

        tl.fromTo(infoBG2, .3, {height: "0"}, {height: "100%"})
          .fromTo(infoBG, .3, {height: "0"}, {height: "100%"}, 0.25)
          .to(infoBG, .4, {height: "84%"})
          .to(infoBG, .3, {height: "86%"})
          .to(infoBG, .2, {height: "85%"})
          .fromTo([line1, line2], 0.2, {width: "0px"}, {width: "30px"}, 1)
          .to(line1, .2, {css:{rotation: 45, transformOrigin: "50% 50%"}}, 1.4)
          .to(line2, .2, {css:{rotation: -45, transformOrigin: "50% 50%"}}, 1.4);

    function showText() {
        elemObject.fadeIn();
    }
};
```

I realise that I should probably cache $(this) in a variable and reference that in the conditional statements but surely that can't be the root of the issue?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, please feel free to have a look over the actual script file and criticise any part of it - gotta learn through criticism!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side-note: I am a little concerned to see hard-wired tests like `if ($(this).is('.first')) {`. A better approach is to data-drive selections using `data-` attributes to specify target values.

Comment: This might be more for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Another side-note, a bit of refactoring (especially on your if statements) I believe would improve performance, which would be more suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help guys. It's always really good to see what approach people who've been doing this much longer than me take to the same problem. It seems I have a long way to go yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the ideas from Martijn and TrueBlueAussie, you could refactor your code by using data attribute on your target elements:

```
info.click(function(){
    var gp = $(this).parent().parent(),
        gpInfoBG2 = gp.parent().siblings(".info-bg-close"),
        gpInfoBG = gp.parent().siblings(".info-bg"), 
        position = $(this).data('position'),
        infotext;

    switch (position) {
        case 'first': 
           infotext = '.infotext-one';
           break;
        case 'second': 
           infotext = '.infotext-two';
           break;
        case 'third': 
           infotext = '.infotext-three';
           break;
    }

    gp[0].style.display = 'none';
    backgroundIn(gp.siblings(infotext), gpInfoBG, gpInfoBG2);
    gp.siblings(infotext).addClass('open');
});
```

**EDIT**

A suggested fix taken from this post [Greensock slow on mobile devices](http://greensock.com/forums/topic/7842-greensock-slow-on-mobile-devices/) is to "set a small z value which will typically force the browser to push the element to the GPU, thus applying the matrix gets done at the GPU instead of the CPU. This isn't a magic bullet, though, because there are costs involved in pushing things to the GPU (not related to GSAP) and it only has a certain amount of memory, so don't try doing this with 1000 elements all at once." For example:

```
//if this is your original tween...
tl.to(line1, .2, {rotation:45});

//to force it onto the gpu, you can simply add z:0.1:
tl.to(line1, .2, {rotation:45, z:0.1});
```

Comment: Just input this into the site, unfortunately it doesn't seem like it's made any difference to the animation running really poorly. Thanks though for teach me about 'data-position'

Comment: A close inspection of the function `backgroundIn()`'s internals will reveal it's doing a lot of chained css transformations which may be causing the animation to run slowly, would be compelled to break down each behaviour into separate method calls https://greensock.com/get-started-js#NDHTC93KA1L3QGFIxYIs

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the background/rotation(tranform). If you can change that to css classes, that might improve speed. To my experience, css animation foes smoother than javascript animation. Apart from that, some small tweaks might help a bit:

```
// you could change this:
gp.css({"display": "none"});
// to:
gp[0].style.display = 'none';
```

And if you give your element a `data-position` value you can drop the elseif and replace that with a switch (this skipping the `.is()` checks:

```
switch( $(this).data('position'){
    case 'first': 
        // stuff
    break;
    case 'second': 
        // stuff
    break;
}
```

Comment: Wish you could share the correct answers on this thing! Thanks for this Martijn, really appreciate it!